# Optimization and fence size

Tags: calculus, optimization

A fence is to be built to enclose a rectangular area of $250$ square feet. The fence along three sides is to be made of material that costs $6$ dollars per foot, and the material for the fourth side costs $15$ dollars per foot. Find the dimensions of the enclosure that is most economical to construct. This problem is looking for the dimensions that will produce the minimum cost. 
The area is $250$ $ft^2$. A rectangle has to have two sides equal to one length, and two sides equal to another. I figured out that one side is equal to $10$ $ft$. What would the other side be equal to? How would I determine that? What would be the proper calculations?

Comment: If you are right about $10$, then $25$. Remember that area is $250$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be the length of the side that costs $15$ per foot, and let $y$ be the length of one of the sides perpendicular to this one. Draw a labelled picture.

The total cost is $15x+6x+6y+6y=21x+12y$. We want to minimize this, given that $xy=250$. A standard way to solve the problem is to substitute $250/x$ for $y$. Then the cost $C(x)$ as a function of $x$ is given by
$$C(x)=21x+\frac{3000}{x}.$$
Use standard tools from the calculus to minimize $C(x)$.

Answer (score -1):

Carrying on from André Nicolas's answer, by [AM-GM](https://brilliant.org/wiki/arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean/), $\frac{1}{2}(21x + \frac{3000}{x}) ≥ \sqrt{21x \cdot \frac{3000}{x}}$.

Simplifying, $\frac{1}{2}(21x + \frac{3000}{x}) ≥ \sqrt{(3 \cdot 7)(3 \cdot100\cdot10)}$, so $21x + \frac{3000}{x} ≥ 60\sqrt{70}$. Can you continue?

Comment: Why is this downvoted?