# how do i solve this related rates problem?

Tags: calculus

A homeowner has 500 dollars to spend on construction of a rectangular fence. One side will cost 20 dollars per meter and the other 3 sides will cost 10 dollars per meter. What is the largest area that the fence can enclose?

Comment: $\max\limits_{x,y} xy$ subject to $20x+10(x+2y)\leq 500$... Then [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Federico I would use an equality as a constraint: $20x+10(x+2y)= 500$

Comment: @callculus You don't know that *a priori*. What if the problem were to minimize the area? It's part of the problem being able to show that you can do that.

Comment: Note that $(ma+nb)^2-(ma-nb)^2=4mnab$ which can be useful in perimeter/area questions.

Comment: Also, duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367602/optimization-and-fence-size?rq=1

Comment: @Federico This is a complete different problem. It has nothing to do whether you minimize or maximize the area. It is obvious that the homeowner wants to spend all 500 dollars.

Comment: @Federico It is not a duplicate of the one, because that is about minimising the cost for given area, and this is about maximising the area for given cost.

Comment: @MarkBennet You are right, i didn't read carefully the other question. Still, they are very much related

Comment: @callculus It is not *obvious* that the owner wants to spend all of his money. When you go to buy something, do you decide beforehand that you want to spend exactly 52.37€, or do you decide what your maximum budget is?

Comment: @Federico Here it is obvious that you need to spend everything, because if you spend proportion $p$ of the total available and $0\lt p\lt 1$ you can scale every length by $1/p$ to increase the area by $1/p^2$ and spend all the money on a larger enclosure.

Comment: @Federico But he wants to maximize the area. The maximum budget is equal to the money he/she will spend. It isn't so difficult to understand it.  At your posted l[ink](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367602/optimization-and-fence-size?rq=1) the answer works with equality as well.

Comment: @MarkBennet Yes, thanks, that was already very clear to me... I only said that it is an integral part of the problem to show that. Therefore in my first comment I only rephrased the problem without giving any hints

Comment: @callculus Oh come on! Of course the optimum **in this case** is achieved when you spend all of it. But it is not always true in a general optimization problem. Hence it is a good habit to formulate the problem without *a priori* assumptions and then reason about it

Comment: @Federico I can comprehend your arguments more or less. My main problem at your first comment was that your link (lagrange multiplier) works with equalities. Beside this, I wish you a Merry Christmas.

Comment: @callculus And in fact, between formulating the problem and using Lagrange multipliers one has to perform some simplification of the constraint, of course. My objection was to your statement "I would use an equality as a constraint". To me, that only follows as a consequence from an initial formulation with an inequality constraint. Happy new year also to you :)

Answer (score 1):

For a rectangle the cost C will be

$C = 20L + 30W = 500$

Rearranging

$L = 25 - 1.5W$

Area $A = L\cdot W = W(25 - 1.5W) = 25W - 1.5W^2$

Area is a max when $dA/dW = 0$

$25 - 3W = 0$

$W = 8\frac{1}{3}\ \text{and}\ L = 12\frac{1}{2}$

So the largest area $A = 104\frac{1}{6} m^2$

Comment: Thanks for the help!